# Why does this basic 'Select Into' stored procedure not work?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, procedure, declare

I'm running Oracle SQL developer and I've got the following Stored Procedure. I'm quite new to this but really not sure why this isn't working:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CHECKDUPLICATE(
       username1 IN USERS.USERNAME%TYPE,
       o_username OUT USERS.USERNAME%TYPE
)

IS
BEGIN

  SELECT USERNAME
  INTO o_username
  FROM USERS WHERE username1 = o_username;

END;
```

When I try to call it:

```
DECLARE
   o_username USERS.USERNAME%TYPE;
BEGIN

   CHECKDUPLICATE('Jacklin', o_username);

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('username :  ' || o_username);

END;
```

I get the error message:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
DECLARE
   o_username USERS.USERNAME%TYPE;
BEGIN

   CHECKDUPLICATE(Jacklin, o_username);

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('username :  ' || o_username);

END;
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 5, column 19:
PLS-00201: identifier 'JACKLIN' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 5, column 4:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

What does it mean by "Identifier 'Jacklin' must be declared? (Table is called USERS, and column name is called USERNAME). Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT** I put Jacklin in quotes, and I get this message now:

```
Error report:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "L13JAV04.CHECKDUPLICATE", line 9
ORA-06512: at line 6
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Even though Jacklin does it exist in the database!

Comment: Jacklin is a string. Should be enclosed in single quotes

Comment: Thanks! But I'm getting another error message now..Error report:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "L13JAV04.CHECKDUPLICATE", line 9
ORA-06512: at line 6
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: I edited it into my original question for easier reading

Comment: what do you intend to do in your where clause `FROM USERS WHERE username1 = o_username;` you are comparing your in and out parameters? if you have a column name called `username1` then you should use table alias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you quote 'Jacklin' so that it's treated as a string literal rather than an identifier, your SQL statement doesn't look right.

```
  SELECT USERNAME
  INTO o_username
  FROM USERS 
  WHERE username1 = o_username;
```

My wager is that you want to use the input parameter in your `WHERE` clause, not the output parameter.

```
  SELECT USERNAME
  INTO o_username
  FROM USERS 
  WHERE username1 = username;
```

It doesn't make sense to check the value of an output parameter when you haven't done anything to initialize it.

But your code still doesn't seem to make sense.  A `SELECT INTO` will throw an error if anything other than 1 row is returned.  If your query returns 0 rows, you'll get a `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception.  If your query returns more than 1 row, you'll get a `TOO_MANY_ROWS` exception.  Your procedure is named `CheckDuplicate` so I'm guessing that it's purpose is to check whether a particular username already exists in the table rather than trying to insert it and catching the unique constraint violation error.  If that is the intention of your code

- You probably want it to be a function
- You probably don't want to return the `username`
- You probably want to return an indicator of whether the username already exists

My guess, therefore, is that you would want something like

```
create or replace function isAvailable( p_username IN USERS.USERNAME%TYPE )
  return Boolean
is
  l_username USERS.USERNAME%TYPE;
begin
  select username
    into l_username
    from users
   where username = p_username;
  return false;
exception
  when no_data_found
  then
    return true;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put Jacklin within quotes for it to be treateed as a string.  Otherwise the parser thinks it's a field name.

Comment: I did that, but I am getting another error message (Edited into original question)

Comment: See Jafar's comment.  Your where clause is wrong. FROM USERS WHERE username1 = o_username should be replaced with FROM USERS WHERE username1 = USERNAME_FIELD_IN_TABLE (whatever that is).

Answer (score 0):

There would have been no user by name of "Jacklin" thats why its giving you the error. Please add an exception at the end

```
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND 
THEN
......
```